# Image is stretching while Pinch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm getting images from remote server and displaying in UIImageView then doing pinch gesture to this imageview. But when i pinching image, i'm getting image stretching. It's loosing original resolution and quality.

```
mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];
 [self.view addSubview:mmageView];

 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *dbpinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dbhandlePinch:)];
 [mmageView addGestureRecognizer:dbpinchGesture];
```

UIPinchGesture:

```
 -(void)dbhandlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

 if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
 // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
 LastScale = [recognizer scale];
 }

 if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
 [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

 CGFloat currentScale = [[[recognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

 // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
 // const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.0;
 const CGFloat kMinScale = 0.8;

 CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (LastScale - [recognizer scale]);
 // newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
 newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[recognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
 [recognizer view].transform = transform;

 LastScale = [recognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
 }

 }
```

Comment: That's probably expected, CGAffineTransformScale isn't going to preserve quality.

Comment: set the imageview content mode aspect fit

Comment: Can you give any sample code?

Comment: imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; Is it?

Comment: yes,  is it not working for you ???

Comment: Should i use below code ? mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];

Comment: mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];
mmageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: No. It's not working for me. I'm loosing original resolution of image

Comment: what is actual image size ?

Comment: check my answer. if it is working for you please accept the answer.

Comment: Image actual size in database 1000x568..

Comment: @Spynet: Does original image size cause problem? Because i used different CGRect in code

Answer (score 1):

For pinch zoom add your imageView in a scrollView and Import `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //for pinch gesture
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
    _scrollView.delegate = self;

}
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return _imageView;
}
```

Comment: Did you subview imageview on scrollview

Comment: did you  Import ' <UIScrollViewDelegate> ' ?

Comment: Check delegate connect with scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` makes supporting the pinch gestures for zooming easy. Better solution in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html).